# App Force Closes when trying to do HTTP URL Connect

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Programming. This is my first app. As part of the app, when i click on a button, I am trying to connect to a URL using the HTTP URL Connect method described on the android documentation. However, my app force closes the moment I click on the button. I have added Internet access and Access Network State permissions in my manifest file as well. 
Following is my code :

```
public class GET_PNR extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 private String readStream(InputStream is) {
        try {
          ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          int i = is.read();
          while(i != -1) {
            bo.write(i);
            i = is.read();
          }
          return bo.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          return "";
        }
    }
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get__pnr);
    View txtview = findViewById(R.id.get_pnr);
    txtview.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.get__pnr, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView pnrview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PNR);
    CharSequence input;
    input = pnrview.getText();
    System.out.println(input);
    String result;

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null; 
    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        result = readStream(in);
       System.out.println(result);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
         finally {
             urlConnection.disconnect();
           }
     }
}
```

Some help in this regard will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: 100% sure you got a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Google that.

Comment: the Exception you get doesn't happen to be a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception/6343299#6343299) does it?

Comment: Yup! I did get NetworkOnMainThreadException.
So, any help with how to shift this to a new thread?

Answer (score 0):

In the last versions of Android, the OS will prevent you from doing Networking in the main thread, you should move your code to a worker thread, either creating your own Thread, or making use of Android API AsyncTask in order to successfully execute your program...

Hope this helps.

Regards!